# Passing a value back TO ADF from a databricks Python node

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-databricks

In Azure DF I run python code using a Databricks.Python node.  What I am trying to do is return a value from the Python script (e.g. print(value_to_return)) and use this to set the value of a variable which will be used by another node (web).

Is there anyway of returning a value form a python script that is run from an ADF pipeline.  I know I can do it using the Databricks.NoteBook node and adding dbutils.notebook.exit() at the end, but I am really trying to achieve this using the the Python node.

The repeating solution I see is to write the value to a file/db table and then read it back and set the variable value that way.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no. You can only call a Python script, it cannot return a custom value to the output of the Python node in ADF to be used as an input to another node in the pipeline.